# Using XSLT insert a new node with hyperlink

Tags: xml, xslt

Im new to XSL. Here is the XML i have, by applying xsl i want to insert a new node inside the elements/element node. See below the output im getting now and the expected output. also i m pasting the xsl i used to get the nodes as output. Please provide a change to the xsl so that it can insert a new node and display the same in the hierarchy.

Please provide your valuable inputs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plans xmlns="http://test.org/schema/product/v1">
<plan effDate="2013-07-01" endDate="9999-12-31" id="MD0000002524" source="PDM" state="RELEASED" version="I.8" vertical="MEDICAL">
    <!--Generated by: GeneratePDMCanonical ver. 16.4-->
    <!--Codeset version 1.6-->
    <!--Generated by: FilterPDM ver. 8-->
    <ids WINDCHILL="MD0000002524">
        <id type="WINDCHILL">1</id>
        <id type="BOC">1</id>
    </ids>
    <planInfo>
        <productInfo source="PDM">
            <claimAdjudicationBeginDate>2013-07-01</claimAdjudicationBeginDate>
            <items>
                <!--Unmapped items-->
                <item name="baselineId">000000</item>
            </items>
            <indicators>
                <indicator type="HSAQualified">false</indicator>
                <!--Unmapped indicators-->
                <indicator type="hsaQualified">false</indicator>
            </indicators>
            <versionInfo>
                <version>I</version>
            </versionInfo>
        </productInfo>
        <forms>
            <form id="FR0000001378" type="FilingForm" version="A.1">
                <formType>MA PPO</formType>
                <legalEntity>Company</legalEntity>
                <ratingState>MA</ratingState>
                <items>
                    <!--Unmapped items-->
                    <item name="contentBaselineNumber"/>
                </items>
            </form>
            <form id="1379" type="HandbookForm" version="A.1">
                <formType>Fully Insured</formType>
                <formNumber/>
            </form>
        </forms>
        <!--Plan Level Networks-->
        <networks id="Plan">
            <network id="NT0300000029" name="Tier 3" version="A.1">
                <networkCode>029</networkCode>
                <networkName>Tier 3</networkName>
                <networkType>IN</networkType>
                <networkLevel>3</networkLevel>
            </network>
        </networks>
    </planInfo>
    <elements>
        <!--Plan-Level Deductibles-->
        <element id="BN000001" parent="BN09" type="" version="A.3">
            <forService>Breast </forService>
            <elementValue forService="Breast "/>
            <!--Defined for plans with fundingArrangement: Fully Insured-->
            <indicators>
                <indicator type="referralRequired">false</indicator>
                <indicator type="payAlways">false</indicator>
            </indicators>
            <networks ref="Plan"/>
            <defaultCMSLocation>12</defaultCMSLocation>
            <!--costshare applies:applyCoinsurance|applyDeductible|applyOONCoins|applyOONDeductible|applyToOOPMax-->
            <element name="20% 1" networkType="IN" ref="C005" type="CoInsurance" version="A.7"/>
            <element name="$1000 IN -  Tier 1" networkType="IN" ref="DD0" type="Deductible" version="B.2"/>
        </element>
    </elements>
</plan>
```

XSL: Will display only the nodes with hyperlink

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <div class="l-d">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()"/>

<xsl:template match="*[*]">
        <div class="l-d-t1">
            <div class="l-d-t1-t2">
                <a href="#" onclick="f_l_nav(this);" class="l-d-t1-t2-a">-</a>
        <span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-xpath"><xsl:for-each select="ancestor::*">/<xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>[<xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*[name()=name(current())])+1"/>]</xsl:for-each>/<xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>[<xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*[name()=name(current())])+1"/>]</span>
                <span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-name" onclick="f_l_nav(this,1);">
                    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                </span>
            </div>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Actual Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><div class="l-d"><div class="l-d-t1"><div class="l-d-t1-t2"><a href="#" onclick="f_l_nav(this);" class="l-d-t1-t2-a">-</a><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-xpath">/plans[1]</span><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-name" onclick="f_l_nav(this,1);">plans</span></div><div class="l-d-t1"><div class="l-d-t1-t2"><a href="#" onclick="f_l_nav(this);" class="l-d-t1-t2-a">-</a><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-xpath">/plans[1]/plan[1]</span><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-name" onclick="f_l_nav(this,1);">plan</span></div><div class="l-d-t1"><div class="l-d-t1-t2"><a href="#" onclick="f_l_nav(this);" class="l-d-t1-t2-a">-</a><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-xpath">/plans[1]/plan[1]/ids[1]</span><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-name" onclick="f_l_nav(this,1);">ids</span></div></div><div class="l-d-t1"><div class="l-d-t1-t2"><a href="#" onclick="f_l_nav(this);" class="l-d-t1-t2-a">-</a><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-xpath">/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]</span><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-name" onclick="f_l_nav(this,1);">planInfo</span></div><div class="l-d-t1"><div class="l-d-t1-t2"><a href="#" onclick="f_l_nav(this);" class="l-d-t1-t2-a">-</a><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-xpath">/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/productInfo[1]</span><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-name" onclick="f_l_nav(this,1);">productInfo</span></div><div class="l-d-t1"><div class="l-d-t1-t2"><a href="#" onclick="f_l_nav(this);" class="l-d-t1-t2-a">-</a><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-xpath">/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/productInfo[1]/items[1]</span><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-name" onclick="f_l_nav(this,1);">items</span></div></div><div class="l-d-t1"><div class="l-d-t1-t2"><a href="#" onclick="f_l_nav(this);" class="l-d-t1-t2-a">-</a><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-xpath">/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/productInfo[1]/indicators[1]</span><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-name" onclick="f_l_nav(this,1);">indicators</span></div></div><div class="l-d-t1"><div class="l-d-t1-t2"><a href="#" onclick="f_l_nav(this);" class="l-d-t1-t2-a">-</a><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-xpath">/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/productInfo[1]/versionInfo[1]</span><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-name" onclick="f_l_nav(this,1);">versionInfo</span></div></div></div><div class="l-d-t1"><div class="l-d-t1-t2"><a href="#" onclick="f_l_nav(this);" class="l-d-t1-t2-a">-</a><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-xpath">/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/forms[1]</span><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-name" onclick="f_l_nav(this,1);">forms</span></div><div class="l-d-t1"><div class="l-d-t1-t2"><a href="#" onclick="f_l_nav(this);" class="l-d-t1-t2-a">-</a><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-xpath">/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/forms[1]/form[1]</span><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-name" onclick="f_l_nav(this,1);">form</span></div><div class="l-d-t1"><div class="l-d-t1-t2"><a href="#" onclick="f_l_nav(this);" class="l-d-t1-t2-a">-</a><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-xpath">/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/forms[1]/form[1]/items[1]</span><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-name" onclick="f_l_nav(this,1);">items</span></div></div></div><div class="l-d-t1"><div class="l-d-t1-t2"><a href="#" onclick="f_l_nav(this);" class="l-d-t1-t2-a">-</a><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-xpath">/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/forms[1]/form[2]</span><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-name" onclick="f_l_nav(this,1);">form</span></div></div></div><div class="l-d-t1"><div class="l-d-t1-t2"><a href="#" onclick="f_l_nav(this);" class="l-d-t1-t2-a">-</a><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-xpath">/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/networks[1]</span><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-name" onclick="f_l_nav(this,1);">networks</span></div><div class="l-d-t1"><div class="l-d-t1-t2"><a href="#" onclick="f_l_nav(this);" class="l-d-t1-t2-a">-</a><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-xpath">/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/networks[1]/network[1]</span><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-name" onclick="f_l_nav(this,1);">network</span></div></div><div class="l-d-t1"><div class="l-d-t1-t2"><a href="#" onclick="f_l_nav(this);" class="l-d-t1-t2-a">-</a><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-xpath">/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/networks[1]/network[2]</span><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-name" onclick="f_l_nav(this,1);">network</span></div></div><div class="l-d-t1"><div class="l-d-t1-t2"><a href="#" onclick="f_l_nav(this);" class="l-d-t1-t2-a">-</a><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-xpath">/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/networks[1]/network[3]</span><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-name" onclick="f_l_nav(this,1);">network</span></div></div><div class="l-d-t1"><div class="l-d-t1-t2"><a href="#" onclick="f_l_nav(this);" class="l-d-t1-t2-a">-</a><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-xpath">/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/networks[1]/network[4]</span><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-name" onclick="f_l_nav(this,1);">network</span></div></div><div class="l-d-t1"><div class="l-d-t1-t2"><a href="#" onclick="f_l_nav(this);" class="l-d-t1-t2-a">-</a><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-xpath">/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/networks[1]/network[5]</span><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-name" onclick="f_l_nav(this,1);">network</span></div></div></div><div class="l-d-t1"><div class="l-d-t1-t2"><a href="#" onclick="f_l_nav(this);" class="l-d-t1-t2-a">-</a><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-xpath">/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/networks[2]</span><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-name" onclick="f_l_nav(this,1);">networks</span></div><div class="l-d-t1"><div class="l-d-t1-t2"><a href="#" onclick="f_l_nav(this);" class="l-d-t1-t2-a">-</a><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-xpath">/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/networks[2]/network[1]</span><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-name" onclick="f_l_nav(this,1);">network</span></div></div><div class="l-d-t1"><div class="l-d-t1-t2"><a href="#" onclick="f_l_nav(this);" class="l-d-t1-t2-a">-</a><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-xpath">/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/networks[2]/network[2]</span><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-name" onclick="f_l_nav(this,1);">network</span></div></div></div></div><div class="l-d-t1"><div class="l-d-t1-t2"><a href="#" onclick="f_l_nav(this);" class="l-d-t1-t2-a">-</a><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-xpath">/plans[1]/plan[1]/elements[1]</span><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-name" onclick="f_l_nav(this,1);">elements</span></div><div class="l-d-t1"><div class="l-d-t1-t2"><a href="#" onclick="f_l_nav(this);" class="l-d-t1-t2-a">-</a><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-xpath">/plans[1]/plan[1]/elements[1]/element[1]</span><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-name" onclick="f_l_nav(this,1);">element</span></div><div class="l-d-t1"><div class="l-d-t1-t2"><a href="#" onclick="f_l_nav(this);" class="l-d-t1-t2-a">-</a><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-xpath">/plans[1]/plan[1]/elements[1]/element[1]/indicators[1]</span><span class="l-d-t1-t2-s-name" onclick="f_l_nav(this,1);">indicators</span></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Expected output:

-/plans[1]plans-/plans[1]/plan[1]plan-/plans[1]/plan[1]/ids[1]ids-/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]planInfo-/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/productInfo[1]productInfo-/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/productInfo[1]/items[1]items-/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/productInfo[1]/indicators[1]indicators-/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/productInfo[1]/versionInfo[1]versionInfo-/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/forms[1]forms-/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/forms[1]/form[1]form-/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/forms[1]/form[1]/items[1]items-/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/forms[1]/form[2]form-/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/networks[1]networks-/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/networks[1]/network[1]network-/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/networks[1]/network[2]network-/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/networks[1]/network[3]network-/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/networks[1]/network[4]network-/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/networks[1]/network[5]network-/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/networks[2]networks-/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/networks[2]/network[1]network-/plans[1]/plan[1]/planInfo[1]/networks[2]/network[2]network-/plans[1]/plan[1]/elements[1]elements-/plans[1]/plan[1]/elements[1]/element[1]element-/plans[1]/plan[1]/elements[1]/element[1]/indicators[1]indicators***-/plans[1]/plan[1]/elements[1]/element[1]/reference[1]reference***<

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question looks good. But first complete your last, very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578593/insert-new-node. It seems you did not look at my answer. Either leave a comment or accept the answer (mark the tick on the left).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it this way: copy every node other than elements/element/element. and create reference and then put elements/element/element in it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:pre="http://test.org/schema/product/v1" exclude-result-prefixes="pre">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pre:elements/pre:element">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(local-name() = 'element')] | @*"/>
        <pre:reference>
                <xsl:copy-of select="pre:element"/>
        </pre:reference>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This creates too much output. Besides, the namespace is duplicated on the newly inserted elements: `<pre:reference xmlns:pre="http://test.org/schema/product/v1">`.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution builds upon the answer I have given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578593/insert-new-node) already. Actually, you could have used the information there to enhance your current stylesheet and solve half of your problem (i.e. insert a `reference` element).

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:v1="http://test.org/schema/product/v1"
   exclude-result-prefixes="v1">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="*[*]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[*]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="v1:element[*]">
        <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
           <xsl:element name="reference" namespace="http://test.org/schema/product/v1">
              <xsl:for-each select="v1:element">
               <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
               </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
           </xsl:element>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<plans xmlns="http://test.org/schema/product/v1">
   <plan>
      <ids/>
      <planInfo>
         <productInfo>
            <items/>
            <indicators/>
            <versionInfo/>
         </productInfo>
         <forms>
            <form>
               <items/>
            </form>
            <form/>
         </forms>
         <networks>
            <network/>
         </networks>
      </planInfo>
      <elements>
         <element>
            <indicators/>
            <reference>
               <element name="20% 1" networkType="IN" ref="C005" type="CoInsurance" version="A.7"/>
               <element name="$1000 IN -  Tier 1" networkType="IN" ref="DD0" type="Deductible"
                        version="B.2"/>
            </reference>
         </element>
      </elements>
   </plan>
</plans>
```

Comment: mathias, but i want to retain the template <a href> and div tag.. as all the nodes coming in the output are hyperlinked. upon clicking the link it ll pass the xpath to another xsl and fetch the data from the XML.

Comment: In your expected output XML, _nothing_ is a hyperlink. What do you mean? Also, please complete your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578593/insert-new-node by accepting the solution if it solved your problem.

Comment: - plans
- plan
+ ids
+ planInfo
+ elements  the o/p will com like this.. when u click + the sub nodes will expand. for tht reason only i hv used. <a href="#" onclick="f_l_nav(this);" class="l-d-t1-t2-a">-</a> and div tags